# using mapDispatchToProps in react component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have the problem that i cannot find a way to get the mapDispatchToProps into my react component. since it is a class.

This is the class where i have the problem, i get the error: 'findPosts' is not defined.

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  findPosts: searchPosts
};

class SearchMenu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null,
    value: ''
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value,});
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

  render() {
    const { anchorEl } = this.state;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <IconButton onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <SearchIcon color="secondary" />
        </IconButton>
        <Menu
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
        >
          <MenuItem>
            <CategorySelector />
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>
            <TextField
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <IconButton onClick={() => { findPosts(this.state.value); }}>
              <SearchIcon color="secondary" />
            </IconButton>
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(SearchMenu);
```

In other components I was able to do this because I could use something like this:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getPosts: fetchPosts
};

const Reactions = ({ getPosts}) => (
<LinkButton onClick={() => {getPosts("messages");}}>
  Back to posts
</LinkButton>
);

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Reactions);
```

But because I need the this.setState in the bit of code, I am not able to change it like in the second example.

Comment: You need to call it with this.props.findPosts since it is not imported like a function parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class you have to use `this.props.findPosts(this.state.value)`